# video player condition is not working with javascript in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, laravel, html5-video

I am making a video website using Laravel and JS. To play the videos I'm using video tag ().
There are many conditions to play the video. Like: If user is not logged in then video will be paused after 20 seconds. After login if video is free then video will be play completely. But if video is paid and user did not pay for the video then the user can watch till 20 seconds only. and few more conditions are there.
In chrome all the conditions are working perfectly. But in Mozilla it does not working.
Like: If user is loggedin and he did not pay for the video then the video will be play till only 20 seconds and a message will be shown on the videos. It works on chrome.
But at the mozilla the same video does not pause at the 20 seconds.

Here is the my js code.

```
    <script>
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.myVideo');
    let playing = [];
console.log(routename);



    videos.forEach(async (video, index) => {
        const overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay')[index];
        const paymentoverlay = document.querySelectorAll('.paymentoverlay')[index];

        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', async function () {
            console.log('1');
            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', async function () {
                console.log('2');
                if (!isUserLoggedIn && video.currentTime >= 20 && !video.paused && playing.includes(video)) {
                console.log('3');
                    video.pause();
                    video.controls = false;
                    overlay.style.display = 'block'; // Show the "Please login to continue watching" overlay
                } else {
                    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                        if (await isFreeVideo(video)) {
                            console.log('4');
                            // Video will play.
                        } else {
                            if ((await isPaidVideo(video) && await hasPaid(video)) || (await isMemberVideo(video) && await isMembershipActive())) {
                                // Video will play.
                                console.log('5');
                            } else {
                                console.log('6');
                                if (!video.paused && video.currentTime >= 20) {
                                    console.log('7');
                                    video.pause();
                                    video.controls = false;
                                    paymentoverlay.style.display = 'block'; // Show the "Please pay first" overlay
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        video.onplay = function () {
            playing.push(video);
            if (!video.paused) {
                video.controls = true;
            }
        };

        video.onpause = function () {
            if (!video.paused) {
                video.controls = false;
            }
        };
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', async function (event) {
        if (!event.target.classList.contains('myVideo') && !event.target.classList.contains('play-icon')) {
            videos.forEach(async (video, index) => {
                const overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay')[index];
                const paymentoverlay = document.querySelectorAll('.paymentoverlay')[index];

                if (!playing.includes(video) && !isUserLoggedIn && event.target.classList.contains('play-icon')) {
                    if (!(await isFreeVideo(video)) && !(await hasPaid(video)) && !(await isMembershipActive())) {
                        video.pause();
                        video.controls = false;
                        overlay.style.display = 'block'; // Show the "Please login to continue watching" overlay
                    } else if (await isPaidVideo(video) && !await hasPaid(video)) {
                        paymentoverlay.style.display = 'block'; // Show the "Please pay first" overlay
                    }
                }
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    // Helper functions
    async function isFreeVideo(video) {
        const videoId = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
        const response = await fetch(`{{ route('video.isFree', ['videoId' => ':videoId']) }}`.replace(':videoId', videoId));
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.isFree;
    }

    async function isPaidVideo(video) {
        const videoId = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
        const response = await fetch(`{{ route('video.isPaid', ['videoId' => ':videoId']) }}`.replace(':videoId', videoId));
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.isPaid;
    }

    async function hasPaid(video) {
        const videoId = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
        const response = await fetch(`{{ route('video.hasPaid', ['videoId' => ':videoId']) }}`.replace(':videoId', videoId));
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.hasPaid;
    }

    async function isMemberVideo(video) {
        const videoId = video.getAttribute('data-video-id');
        const response = await fetch(`{{ route('video.isMember', ['videoId' => ':videoId']) }}`.replace(':videoId', videoId));
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.isMember;
    }

    async function isMembershipActive() {
        const response = await fetch(`{{ route('user.isMembershipActive') }}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.isMembershipActive;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Quick question: are you using different URLs/versions for the videos? Like a 20sec version of the video? Are you using a project URL for the video or is it the "direct" URL to the video? What stops users from disabling JS and viewing the complete video? What stops users from right-clicking the video element and "Save video as ..." when they're not logged in?

Comment: No video is only one. I don't have any different versions. I have added conditions only on the single video.
The video url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/vide_Upload2_image/1699953088_file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4

Comment: Now anyone can rightclick and enable download option for that video. It is not secure.

Comment: @brombeer, Please have a look and help me for that. I've spoiled my whole day behind this.

Comment: So you want to keep this in-secure client-side validation? Do you get any errors/warnings in the Firefox DevConsole?

Comment: Let me check....

Comment: Now i am working on the client side.
This is the warning:
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 6

Is there any other secure way?

Comment: Can we please connect on anydesk. If you don't have any issue.

Comment: A more secure way would be to _not_ have the client make the validation but the server. Have a script `videhandler.php` or so as `src` that checks if a user is logged in etc, if so, stream the full version of the video, if not, stream the 20sec version.

Comment: "_Can we please connect on anydesk_" Don't have it and don't have the time to guide you through this/code this with you. I can give you hints, you need to code that on your own - or hire someone to do it for you. Sorry. Good luck

Comment: Can you update my code or give me any code?

Comment: @brombeer,
Thank you for help.
The helper functions are checking the validation condition from the server

Comment: `if (... && video.currentTime >= 20...)` certainly is _not_ checked on the server. Users can change 20 to 2000000 (or comment/remove `video.pause();`) and resend the request.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
Thankyou for the help.

Making two versions of the video will be good choice and way.